# Weeknum that doesn't start from 1st every year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i start weeknum from first week in 2018 and go on through 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022... without starting the count from 1 every year. Ex: if 2018 has 44 weeks i want the weeknum(1-1-2019) to return 45 not 1 and so on.

Comment: Can't you just add `(year-2018)*52`?

Comment: `=ROUNDUP(DATEDIF([2018 date],[Later date],"D")/7,0)` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Week starts on Monday use:

```
=INT((A1-"1/1/2018")/7)+1
```

If your week starts on Sunday:

```
=INT((A1-"1/1/2018"+1)/7)+1
```